# 'or' and 'and' evaluation in Python3x

Tags: python

I can't understand why the code below works like this.  (in Python3x)

```
>>>f = lambda: print('Hello') or print('Hello again')

>>>f()

Hello

Hello again
```

and also can't understand like this.

```
>>>f = lambda: print('Hello') and print('Hello again')

>>>f()

Hello
```

For me, the first lambda function seems to print the word 'Hello' **or** the word 'Hello again' but it print **both** 'Hello' **and** 'Hello again'.

The second function seems to print the word 'Hello' **and** 'Hello again' but it print only 'Hello'.

Can anybody explain what is going on in this lambda function?

Thank you for your kind help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` returns None (which is Falseish), so python has to evaluate the other operand of `or`, but not `and`, to get the answer.

- `return print('Hello') or print('Hello again')`
- `Hello` is printed, print returns `None`
- `return None or print('Hello again')`
- `or` returns True if any of the operands is True. If the first one is True, there's no need to evaluate the second one. This isn't the case
- `Hello again` is printed
- `return None or None`
- now we are certain False should be returned.

- `return print('Hello') and print('Hello again')`
- `Hello` is printed, print returns `None`
- `return None and print('Hello again')`
- `and` returns True if both operands are True. If the first one is False, there's no need to evaluate the second one.
- `return False`

Comment: Thank you for a quick response!
I get it.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Lazy evaluation, this means python won't compute more than necessary. in:

```
Expression1 or Expression2
```

and

```
Expression1 and Expression2
```

if the Expression1 is False, in the case of the `or` comparison python will need the result of the Expression2 to compute the result,
but for the `and` comparison if Expression1 is False, then non need to compute the second part of the comparison as `0 and x == False` no matter if x is `True` or `False`
the 2sd function print in the `and` comparison does not need to be evaluated, as python already knows that the comparison will be equal to `False`

The `print` function does not return anything I.e. return `None`

```
>>> def print2(string):
     print(string)
     return True

>>> r=(lambda: print2('Hello') or print2('Hello again'))()
Hello
```

However this will only print the first Hello (because it is true) and never the Hello again

```
>>> r=(lambda: print2('Hello') and print2('Hello again'))()
Hello
Hello again
```

to understand lazy evaluation, try these commands:

```
>>> def p():
     print("foo")
     return True



>>> False and p() and p()

False

>>> True and p() and p()

foo
foo
True

>>> True and (not p()) and p()

foo
False
```